# How to prevent deadlocks without using sync.WaitGroup?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

**concurrent.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// JOBS represents the number of jobs workers do
const JOBS = 2

// WORKERS represents the number of workers
const WORKERS = 5

func work(in <-chan int, out chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for n := range in {
        out <- n * n
    }
    wg.Done()
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    in := make(chan int, JOBS)
    out := make(chan int, JOBS)

    for w := 1; w <= WORKERS; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go work(in, out, &wg)
    }

    for j := 1; j <= JOBS; j++ {
        in <- j
    }
    close(in)

    wg.Wait()
    close(out)
    for r := range out {
        fmt.Println("result:", r)
    }

    // This is a solution but I want to do it with `range out`
    // and also without WaitGroups
    // for r := 1; r <= JOBS; r++ {
    //  fmt.Println("result:", <-out)
    // }
}
```

Example is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/y2I9-zvOyH) on goplay.

Comment: You can't use range without eventually closing the channel, and you can't close the channel without waiting. What is it you're trying to accomplish? (BTW there was a time when WaitGroup didn't exist, and we simply counted tokens from a channel manually, but it's still the same concept in more code)

Comment: You don't need mutexes or atomic counters, the standard way to wait for goroutines before WaitGroup was to count values returned through a channel.

Comment: It depends on the situation, but you have a commented out example right in your own code. You receive the number of of results up until you reach the number of JOBS you dispatched.

Answer (score 3):

Goroutines run concurrently and independently. [Spec: Go statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)

> A "go" statement starts the execution of a function call as an **independent concurrent thread of control**, or *goroutine*, within the same address space.

If you want to use `for range` to receive values from the `out` channel, that means the `out` channel can only be closed once all goroutines are done sending on it.

Since goroutines run concurrently and independently, without synchronization you can't have this.

Using `WaitGroup` is one mean, one way to do it (to ensure we wait all goroutines to do their job before closing `out`).

Your commented code is another way of that: the commented code receives exactly as many values from the channel as many the goroutines ought to send on it, which is only possible if all goroutines do send their values. The synchronization are the send statements and receive operations.

**Notes:**

Usually receiving results from the channel is done asynchronously, in a dedicated goroutine, or using even multiple goroutines. Doing so you are not required to use channels with buffers capable of buffering all the results. You will still need synchronization to wait for all workers to finish their job, you can't avoid this due to the concurrent and independent nature of gorutine scheduling and execution.

Comment: _Different angle:_ In [for statements doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) writes: _'If the channel is nil, the range expression blocks forever.'_ However: When I assign `nil` to `out`, `range out` doesn't block, and it deadlocks (`out = nil` before `range out`). Why?

Comment: @inanc I don't know the code you tried, but: deadlock = all goroutines are blocked, so it implies `range out` is blocked also. If you assign `nil` to `out` then attempt to `for range` on it, the main goroutine will block with no other goroutine to salvage it, and since (or when) workers finish: deadlock.

Comment: I got it. I tried it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/WUDyMa6XtV). It works without `WaitGroup`. This didn't deadlock because `main` is still can run independently of the `range out`.